# Anyone know how to build dropdown menu on xpages without using dojo or extlib?

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I've tried using dojo dropdown menu and its working but when i try to deploy it on domino server which is on VMWare using windows 2003 server, the dojo's not working on dropdown

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoForm="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true" dojoTheme="true">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.MenuBar"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.PopupMenuBarItem"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.Menu"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.MenuItem"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.PopupMenuItem"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.MenuBarItem"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
```

so i've think it would be nice if someone can help me solve it or suggesting some tricks on xpages which to make dropdown menu without using dojo

ps: i tried using jquery but it seems its not compatible ..

Comment: As Michael said, try to find the source of the problem. My guess would be a IDS/IPS/Firewall blocking Javascript. Do iNotes or the ForumDB work? If not, contact your server/network/security colleagues, because something is not configured correctly. Have you checked whether Xpages support was installed with the Domino server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server configuration is the issue it will bite you in other JS areas later on. So rather fix that one. Other JS menus might not work either.

So look for [pure CSS dropdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=pure+css+drop+down+menu)

Comment: Thanks a lot man , its work

but now im confused how to put the scope using ssjs on that pure css method ..

Answer (score 3):

Maby searching the reason why it is not working would be a better solution then trying to build a dropdown menu with javascript only (that will be a lot of work), what seems for me like fighting the symptoms not the core of your prolem.

If you still decide to build the menu with javascript here a hint how to start:

```
    <xp:panel tagName="div" style="">
        <xp:text id="MainMenu">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr value="showMenu();" name="onclick"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "Menu";}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:panel tagName="ul" id="menu" style="display:none">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr value="hideMenu();" name="onclick"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:panel tagName="li">Item 1</xp:panel>
            <xp:panel tagName="li">Item 2</xp:panel>
            <xp:panel tagName="li">Item 3</xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:scriptBlock type="text/javascript">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[//
function showMenu(){
    document.getElementById("#{id:menu}").style.display="block"; };
function hideMenu(){
    document.getElementById("#{id:menu}").style.display="none"; 
};          
            ]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:scriptBlock>
    </xp:panel>
```

Or try googeling for javascript only Dropdown menu you will find some nice looking menus but the most of them will also require a js script added to your application and if they work why shouldnt dojo and jquery.